# Roundtrip safe scala sbt projects in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I've noticed that projects imported from sbt in IntelliJ/scala (13.1.4/0.41.2) will rewrite the order of `sourceFolder` entries in `.idea/modules/foo.iml` when i open in on windows vs. mac. Haven't tried mac vs. mac. Either way, is there a best practice for preventing changes just from opening something after a check-out?

Comment: Is .idea folder in repository? It should be not in version control.

Comment: According to Jetbrains it should be version controlled if you do wish to share your settings across machines andor developers (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067) which is precisely my use case

Comment: From my experience it is bad solution to add to version control system local configuration. Somebody want to use eclipse/vim/emacs (linux, mac, windows). Comment from [your link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067): `Thanks for the very quick and clarifying reply.  In my case they are managed by Maven and SBT, so I can remove them.`, next comment `This is so wrong... A whole lot of files inside .idea store user-specific settings, depending on a variety of different things like ....`

Comment: Having a .idea folder does not prevent anyone from using eclipse/vim/maven. This is a company internal project with a standardized dev environment, so it is useful to our use case. It just happens that even though JetBrains recommends it for this scenario, it seems to be non-deterministic. My question is whether that is a misconfiguration or a flaw.